# Why CSS hover with pseudo element failed?

Tags: css, hover, pseudo-element

I wrote a list item hover effect today, but the result behavior is quite strange:

When hover from Item6 to Item2, everything's ok,
but when hover from Item2 to Item6 & hover the blank area (inside<li>, outside of <p>),
it seems something is blocking the hovering.

Feels like something's wrong with the pseudo element.

Can anyone help me with it? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```js
var li = document.querySelectorAll('li')
li.forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    li.forEach((l) => {
      l.classList.remove('active')
    })
    e.classList.add('active')
  })
})
```

```css
:root {
  --el-color-primary: #409eff;
  --el-color-info: #909399;
  --el-color-primary-rgb: 64, 158, 255;
}

.categories {
  width: 200px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 2.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: var(--el-color-info);
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: .5rem;
}

li {
  margin: .3rem;
}

li p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  padding: .6rem 0 .6rem .8rem;
  margin: 0;
  color: var(--el-color-info);
}

li.active p {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: var(--el-color-primary);
}

li.active {
  background-color: rgba(var(--el-color-primary-rgb), .2);
}

li:not(.active)::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 2.2rem;
  position: relative;
  top: -2.2rem;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  background-color: rgba(var(--el-color-primary-rgb), .1);
  z-index: -99;
  transition: width .4s ease-out;
}

li:not(.active):hover p {
  color: var(--el-color-primary);
}

li:not(.active):hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="categories">
  <li class="active">
    <p>Item 1</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Item 2</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Item 3</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Item 4</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Item 5</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Item 6</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i've added a snippet and your code seems working fine...where's the problem?

Comment: As i mentioned... hover from Item6 to Item2 is fine, but hover from Item2 to Item 6, Item3 and Item5 seems won't be hovered

Comment: The snippet is working fine for me (Edge/WIndows10). What browser and OS are you using? And have you tried the snippet here and does that still give you the problem?

Comment: there's some problem when hovering the blank area (inside<li>, outside of <p>)

Comment: Give `position: relative` to `li` where you put `z-index: 0`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by modifying putting a display: block at li:not(.active)::after instead of an inline-block

```js
var li = document.querySelectorAll('li')
li.forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    li.forEach((l) => {
      l.classList.remove('active')
    })
    e.classList.add('active')
  })
})
```

```css
:root {
  --el-color-primary: #409eff;
  --el-color-info: #909399;
  --el-color-primary-rgb: 64, 158, 255;
}

.categories {
  width: 200px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 2.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: var(--el-color-info);
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: .5rem;
}

li {
  margin: .3rem;
}

li p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  padding: .6rem 0 .6rem .8rem;
  margin: 0;
  color: var(--el-color-info);
}

li.active p {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: var(--el-color-primary);
}

li.active {
  background-color: rgba(var(--el-color-primary-rgb), .2);
}

li:not(.active)::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 2.2rem;
  position: relative;
  top: -2.2rem;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  background-color: rgba(var(--el-color-primary-rgb), .1);
  z-index: -99;
  transition: width .4s ease-out;
}

li:not(.active):hover p {
  color: var(--el-color-primary);
}

li:not(.active):hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="categories">
  <li class="active">
    <p>Item 1</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Item 2</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Item 3</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Item 4</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Item 5</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Item 6</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `top: -2.2rem` because it is relative and `relative` position doesn't remove the element from the normal document flow ([mdn link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#relative)). see how it looks like when we just use `top: 0`:
[image]
The whole selected area shows "item 2" `li` element and the light-blue box is actually a part of that element and we bring it up by negative top value. That's why when we enter mouse from item 2 to 3, we think we would be on item 3 but in fact we are still hovering item 2.

I guess the better way to do this is using `absolute`:

```js
var li = document.querySelectorAll('li')
li.forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    li.forEach((l) => {
      l.classList.remove('active')
    })
    e.classList.add('active')
  })
})
```

```css
:root {
  --el-color-primary: #409eff;
  --el-color-info: #909399;
  --el-color-primary-rgb: 64, 158, 255;
}

.categories {
  width: 200px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 2.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: var(--el-color-info);
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  position: relative; /* <----- new */
}

li {
  margin: .3rem;
}

li p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  padding: .6rem 0 .6rem .8rem;
  margin: 0;
  color: var(--el-color-info);
}

li.active p {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: var(--el-color-primary);
}

li.active {
  background-color: rgba(var(--el-color-primary-rgb), .2);
}

li:not(.active)::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 2.2rem;
  position: absolute; /* <----- new */
  top: 0; /* <----- new */
  left: 0;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  background-color: rgba(var(--el-color-primary-rgb), .1);
  z-index: -99;
  transition: width .4s ease-out;
}

li:not(.active):hover p {
  color: var(--el-color-primary);
}

li:not(.active):hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="categories">
  <li class="active">
    <p>Item 1</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Item 2</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Item 3</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Item 4</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Item 5</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Item 6</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```